# Run `platformio run -v` manually in vscode integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, platformio

When I click on **build** in PlatformIO IDE an integrated terminal is opened, which executes `platformio run`.

Yesterday, when I opened another integrated terminal in the same folder, I was able to execute commands such as `platformio run -v` successfully without any configuration. I see them in my history.

Today I get: `platformio: command not found`

Does anyone know, how to reproduce the first behavior?
I found it very useful to have a "ready to go" terminal just one shortcut away.

I didn't need to export an environment variable or install tools, as said [here](https://docs.platformio.org/en/stable/core/installation.html#unix-and-unix-like).
Neither did I configure the `.ini`-file or click on verbose build, as said [here](https://community.platformio.org/t/how-to-add-verbose-to-platformio-ini/16131).
My system: vscodium 1.64.2 | PlatformIO: Core 5.2.5, Home 3.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I settled to add [PlatformIO CLI](https://docs.platformio.org/en/stable/core/installation.html#method-1) to the shell:

On Linux, add `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.platformio/penv/bin` to `~/.bashrc`.

This way, `pio` and `platformio` are accessible in every instance of bash. If using a different shell, use a the respective configuration file.

Also I suspect that the behavior I observed was achieved by interrupting a shell which was started from PlatformIO GUI. This only works reliably when the building process takes some time and is not the intended way of doing things.